# Why const char * and const char [] as function parameter are considered to be equivalent?

Tags: c++

I know :

```
const char* foo = "ab"; // OK.There is a "array to pointer" decay
const char a[3] = "ab"; // OK.
const char a[2] = "ab"; // Error. "ab" is const char [3]
```

Then why not also distinguishing it when use `const char a[N]`, `const char *` as a function parameter?

Function declaration `void foo(const char *a)` and `void foo(const char a[3])` are considered to be the same. There is no restrictions like `const char a[2] = "ab";` when I call `foo("abcdefg");` The inconsistent(**unsymmetrical**) behavior makes me a little bit curious in the very first moment.

Comment: That's the way the language is specified, and it is a feature that will stay for as long as backward compatibility to C is required.   Passing an array to a function has the same effect as passing a pointer to its first element.   (Unless the array is passed by reference).       In C++, you'd be better of using a standard container (e.g. `std::string`) as function argument, and avoid using pointers or raw arrays directly.

Comment: @Peter C++ is certainly not backward compatible with C, in many ways now.  The issue is that C++ once was mostly backward compatible with C, and now new versions of C++ need to be mostly backward compatible with other versions of C++.

Comment: @aschepler - the conversion of array to a pointer is a feature inherited from C, and it is a form of backward compatibility with C that is unlikely to disappear any time soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) we can find

> The type of each function parameter in the parameter list is determined according to the following rules:
>   ...
>   2) If the type is "array of T" or "array of unknown bound of T", it is replaced by the type "pointer to T"

As to why, i believe it was simply adopted from C like many other language features.

Comment: Damn, how did you even find this on cppreference? Did you read every word on each page of cppreference?

Comment: The answer is convincing. But I always think that every operation should be symmetrical. Apparently this one is not.

Comment: @Rick Is "because language is specified this way" really an acceptable answer? This is a kind of situation like in that experiment with 5 monkeys and water.

Comment: @VTT Honestly, answers like "because language is specified this way" do not satisfy my curiosity. I mean, it does not tell me anything new. So that's why I accepted this one. At least it gives some reference and it's good to know "*2) If the...*". And I just wanna know how the other seniors consider this question and I would be happy if I learn something new.

Comment: @Rick Here's why: C (and C++) passes function parameters "by value", meaning that the value of the parameter is passed to the function on the stack. Passing an array by value would mean copying all of the array elements on the stack, which is impractical for many reasons (possible stack overflow, unknown array dimensions, etc.). So the original language designers took the liberty of simply converting the parameter to a pointer, which can be dereferenced just like an array. It makes sense when you put all the pieces together.

Comment: @Rick ... also ... I strongly recommend all C/C++ programmers read "The C Programming Language" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie (K&R). It's a relatively short read and you'll gain a lot of insight into the language. This is how us old timers originally learned the language. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how the language is specified to work.

If you explicitly want an array as argument you have to use templates and references:

```
template<size_t N>
void foo1(char (&a)[N]);
```

Or use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain C-style arrays:

```
void foo2(std::array<char, 3> a);
```

Or if you want to be able to use either `std::array` or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) then back to templates:

```
template<typename C>
void foo3(C a);
```

The last can take *any* container-type that have the same interface.

---

Example using the above functions:

```
char arr1[3] = "ab";
foo1(arr1);  // Array will *not* decay to a pointer

std::array<char, 3> arr2 = {{ 'a', 'b', 0 }};
foo2(arr2);

std::vector<char> vec1 = { 'a', 'b', 0 };
foo3(vec1);  // Can pass std::vector

std::string str1 = "ab";
foo3(str1);  // Can pass std::string

foo3(arr2);  // Can pass std::array
```